# What's wrong with my recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi everyone I am new to android developing.Now I am learning recyclerView.
So I want to show 1 to 18 number in recycler view.I know that's really easy but I can't do that.An error is appear when I run my apps.I can't find any wrong with my code.

Here is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.niyamat.golfscoreboard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)    findViewById(R.id.fab);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);



    ScoreboardAdapter scoreboardAdapter = new ScoreboardAdapter(getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(scoreboardAdapter);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

}

private ArrayList<HoleNumber> getData() {
    ArrayList results = new ArrayList<HoleNumber>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        HoleNumber holeNumber = new HoleNumber(i);
        results.add(holeNumber);
    }
    return results;
}


}
```

Here is my Adapter

```
package com.example.niyamat.golfscoreboard;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.TextView;

  import java.util.ArrayList;

  /**
   * Created by Niyamat on 12/2/2015.
   */
   public class ScoreboardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScoreboardAdapter.ScoreBoardViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<HoleNumber> mHoleNumbers;

public ScoreboardAdapter(ArrayList<HoleNumber> holeNumbers) {
    mHoleNumbers = holeNumbers;
}

@Override
public ScoreBoardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.scoreboard_layout, parent, false);
    ScoreBoardViewHolder scoreBoardViewHolder = new ScoreBoardViewHolder(view);
    return scoreBoardViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ScoreBoardViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mHoleNumber.setText(mHoleNumbers.get(position).getHoleNumber());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mHoleNumbers.size();
}

public class ScoreBoardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mHoleNumber;
    public ScoreBoardViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mHoleNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.holeNumber);
    }


   }
  }
```

Here is my model

```
package com.example.niyamat.golfscoreboard;

 /**
* Created by Niyamat on 12/2/2015.
  */
 public class HoleNumber {
 private int mHoleNumber;

public HoleNumber(int holeNumber) {
    mHoleNumber = holeNumber;
}

public int getHoleNumber() {
    return mHoleNumber;
}

public void setHoleNumber(int holeNumber) {
    mHoleNumber = holeNumber;
}
}
```

And finally here is my error shown in my logcat when I ran the apps

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.niyamat.golfscoreboard, PID: 2065
                                                                              android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4417)
                                                                                  at com.example.niyamat.golfscoreboard.ScoreboardAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ScoreboardAdapter.java:31)
                                                                                  at com.example.niyamat.golfscoreboard.ScoreboardAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ScoreboardAdapter.java:14)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5217)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5250)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4487)
                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4363)
```

I also updated my code in github
Here is link
https://github.com/niyamatalmass/Golf_Scoreboard

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0`  because Here:`holder.mHoleNumber.setText(mHoleNumbers.get(position).getHoleNumber());` passing `int` to `setText` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code of onBindViewHolder like this

```
holder.mHoleNumber.setText(mHoleNumbers.get(position).getHoleNumber()+"");
```

Comment: I prefer using `String.valueOf(int)`

Comment: @1615903 yes we can do that way also.

Comment: @NiyamatAlmass Most Welcome.